# French Bean Cobra got scorched by sun?

Tags: leaves, beans

Took my bean outside recently and it was just fine for last 2 days when suddenly yesterday 4 or 5 leave got their tips dried out. It is in pot on North facing wall so wonder if that might be due to strong morning sun ? I put it into the place where is more shade so we will see how it will go from there. Also I checked moisture and its just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, seedlings need to be "hardened off", before you can leave them outside, methods include leaving them outside for progressively longer periods of time each day, and letting the seedling wilt inside several times

Comment: Thanks however everything was fine for first week all of the sudden problems started and now its happening to almost all leaves.

Comment: Well some pictures would be helpful, also check the soil deep down, if it is a pot, the soil can get anaerobic, and smell swampy... That is bad